# Django document upload form not displaying in browser

Tags: python, django, pycharm

This is actually a class assignment i am working on. I created models, views and form classes for document upload and registration in django. I have been consulting different tutorials and trying different techniques, that is why there might be different approaches in my codes. Forgive me for that *newbie alert.*

1. First problem: The registration form does not submit to the table (Users). I added users from the admin end and it logs in perfectly.

**Model.py**

```
class Users(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length='10')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length='50')
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length='50')
    username = models.CharField(max_length='50')
    password = models.CharField(max_length='50')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length='50')
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(max_length='12')
    city = models.CharField(max_length='50')
    country = models.CharField(max_length='50')
    usertype = models.CharField(max_length=13)
```

**Form.py**

```
 class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
        #define fields for form
        title = forms.CharField(max_length='10')
        surname = forms.CharField(max_length='10')
        firstname = forms.CharField(max_length='10')
        username = forms.CharField(max_length='50')
        password = forms.PasswordInput()
        email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
        phone = forms.CharField(max_length='15')
        city = forms.CharField(max_length='50')
        country = forms.CharField(max_length='20')
        userlevel = (
            (u'Client', 'Client'),
            (u'Proof Reader', 'Proof Reader'),
            (u'Admin', 'Admin'),
        )
        usertype = forms.ModelChoiceField( widget=forms.Select, queryset=userlevel )

        class Meta:
            model = Users
            fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
            Users = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
            Users.title = self.cleaned_data['title']
            Users.surname = self.cleaned_data['surname']
            Users.firstname = self.cleaned_data['firstname']
            Users.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
            Users.password = self.cleaned_data['password']
            Users.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
            Users.phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
            Users.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
            Users.country = self.cleaned_data['country']
            Users.usertype = self.cleaned_data['usertype']
            if commit:
                Users.save()
                return Users

    def clean_username(self):
                    username = self.cleaned_data['username']
                    try:
                            User.objects.get(username=username)
                    except User.DoesNotExist:
                            return username
                    raise forms.ValidationError("That username is already taken, please select another.")
```

**View.py**

```
def register(request):
    #model = Users
    #check  the request object if there is a method post for a form action
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #handle the form if method is found to be post
        #create a form object
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        context = {'form': RegisterForm}
        #check if form is valid
        if form.is_valid():
            #save form
            Users.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            Users.surname = form.cleaned_data['surname']
            Users.firstname = form.cleaned_data['firstname']
            Users.username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            Users.password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            Users.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            Users.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            Users.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            Users.country = form.cleaned_data['country']
            Users.usertype = form.cleaned_data['usertype']
            #redirect to success page
            return HttpResponseRedirect('register_success')
        else:
            form = RegisterForm()
            #create arguments to check against CSRF attacks
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = RegisterForm()
    return render_to_response('register.html', args)

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('welcome')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('invalid')
        #return render_to_response('auth_view.html')
```

**Template file - register.html**

```
{% extends "main.html" %}
{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Register</h2>

    <form action="" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
  <table> {{ form }} </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

1. Form for document upload also is not displaying. I have no idea why this is happening.

**Models.py**

```
class document(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    statusid = models.ForeignKey('status')
    userID = models.ForeignKey('Users')
    #feedback = models.TextField(blank=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    completion_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    choice = ((u'Audio', 'Audio'), (u'Text', 'Text'))
    filetype = models.CharField(max_length='50')
```

**views.py**

```
def uploaddocs(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        context = {'form': DocumentForm}
        if form.is_valid():
               form.upload()
               return HttpResponseRedirect('upload_success')

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['forms'] = DocumentForm()
    return render_to_response('uploaddocs.html', args)
```

**forms.py**

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    #define fields for form
    model = document
    file = forms.FileField()
    statusid = forms.CharField(max_length='10')
    userID = forms.CharField(max_length='10')
    #feedback = models.TextField(blank=True)
    time = forms.DateTimeField()
    completion_time = forms.DateTimeField()
    choice = ((u'Audio', 'Audio'), (u'Text', 'Text'))
    filetype = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choice)

def upload(self, commit=True):
   document = DocumentForm.save(commit=False)
   document.statusid = self.cleaned_data['statusid']
   document.time = self.cleaned_data['time']
   document.completion_time = self.cleaned_data['completion_time']
   document.filetype = self.cleaned_data['filetype']
   if commit:
       document.upload()
       return document
```

I know this seems like the whole assignment but believe me, this is just the beginning of my many errors to come. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues at work here:

1. As Martin Ogden stated, you should use a `ModelForm` if you want to directly save to the database. That way, you can get rid of your `RegisterForm.save()` method and the explicit assignments in your view (`title = form.cleaned_data['title']` etc.).
2. In your view, `Users.title = form.cleaned_data['title']` does not work as intended: you are assigning to your `Users` *class*, not a specific instance. With a `ModelForm`, you won't need those explicit assignments, but for reference, here is how you could write this with a regular `Form`:

   ```
   if form.is_valid():
       u = Users()  # create a Users instance
       u.title = form.cleaned_data['title']   # assign the title attribute 
       # ...
       u.save()   # save this Users instance
   ```
3. you always need to pass the form *instance* to the template, not the class. So instead of `context = {'form': RegisterForm}` you'd write

   ```
   form = RegisterForm()
   if request.method == "POST":
       form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
       # ...
   context={'form': form}
   ```

   A very useful pattern is the following:

   ```
   def some_view(request):
       form = RegisterModelForm(request.POST or None)
       if form.is_valid()
           form.save()
           return redirect(...)
       context = {'form': form}
       return render_to_response('register.html', context)
   ```

   that way, you only need to create the form instance once.
4. There is a bug in your `Users` Model: you are manually validating that two `Users` instances can't have the same username, but imagine two users are registering at the *exact* same time with the same name: the existence check in `clean_username` will run through for both users, and both instances will be created. It is better to set `unique=True` for fields that need to be unique, because the database can guarantee these kind of things for you (and you don't need to write that custom vali

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're expecting `RegisterForm` to behave like a `ModelForm` instance. If you change `RegisterForm` to inherit from `django.forms.ModelForm` rather than `django.forms.Form` and also add unique=True to the username field on the `Users` model, you will end up with this:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = User
```

Regarding the document form: it seems to be named inconsistently: in the the view it is named `forms` and in the template it is named `form`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks dude... the document upload page now shows... But i am still having issues with the submission of the registration form to the 'Users' table. Thanks for your help... Appreciate it